# Highlight nav link when scrolling down to div using waypoints

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I've been searching on this for a while now and I couldn't find the right solution for me. I kind of put things together from different articles but I can only get the links to highlight and it doesn't seem to remove class when I scroll back up. Also, when I scroll down all the links get highlighted not just the one link associated with the div.

```
 var $navLinks = $('#about-nav > a'); 

      $navLinks.each(function() {
        var $self = $(this);

        $(this).waypoint({
            handler: function() {
              $self.addClass('current');
          }
       });
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waypoints are usually just about connecting links to content through hashtags and matching ids. I don't see that linking in your example, which is probably why it doesn't work for you...  Or maybe it would have been there if you had been more generous with the whole context ;)

You need a relay that pass the current class from the previous to the next and you need a link between the content and the nav link most commonly something like a hashtag that points to the content.

The idea is:

```
<nav>
  <li><a href="#waypoint1">Go to content1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#waypoint2">Go to content2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#waypoint3">Go to content3</a></li>
</nav>
```

And then you've got a content block with all your-waypoints from waypoint1 to waypoint3 inside, like:

```
<div id='your-waypoints'>
   <div id='waypoint1' class='waypoint'>
      blah-blah-blah
   </div>
   <div id='waypoint2' class='waypoint'>
      blah-blah-blah
   </div>
   <div id='waypoint3' class='waypoint'>
      blah-blah-blah
   </div>
</div>
```

Connecting the dots through script, like:

```
function getWaypointNavRef( WaypointId ) {
    return $('nav a[href="#' + WaypointId + '"]');
}

var lastNavRef = null;
function WaypointRelay( WaypointId ) {
   var nextNavRef = getWaypointNavRef( WaypointId );
   if (lastNavRef)
      $(lastNavRef).removeClass('current');
   $(nextNavRef).addClass('current');
   lastNavRef = nextNavRef;
}
```

Which is called from the handler:

```
$('#your-waypoints > .waypoint').each(function () {
        new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById(this.id),
        handler: function (direction) {
            WaypointRelay(this.element.id);
        },
        context: document.getElementById('your-waypoints')
    });
});
```

Which means that is actually the content that links to the nav when you scroll down the page...

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens to any of the links now. var last = null;
  
  function WaypointRelay(next) {
     next = '#' + next;
     if (last)
        $(last).removeClass('current');
        $(next).addClass('current');
        last = next;
    }
  
    var $navLinks = $('#about-nav > a'); 

      $navLinks.each(function() {
        var $self = $(this);

        $(this).waypoint({
            handler: function(direction) {
              WaypointRelay(this.element.id);
          }
       });
     });

Comment: It's probably referring to the wrong id. Please show connection between div and nav.

Comment: I've rephrased my original suggest with a more thorough example.

Comment: I just don’t really understand how those functions get each a tags exactly. Or why you need the function getWaypointNavRef. Or the relay function. Why set lasNavRef value to null? I’m totally lost here. I’ve been studying javascript for a while now and I still can’t write anything that works.. I just don’t understand it. But thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It will probably make more sense with a visual. Here is a very elegant version: https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/mhCyx, he's not using a relay, but toggleClass, but his CSS is also a mile long. He is also using the direction ('up'|'down') to determine when to toggle (on|off).